# Morphisms between quasiprojective varieties preserve irreducibility

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra

> Let $X,Y$ be two quasiprojective varieties and $\phi \colon X \to Y$ a surjective [morphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_varieties). Let $Z \subset Y$ a closed set such that $\phi^{-1}(Z)$ is irreducible. Prove that $Z$ is irreducible.

I do not understand what the exercise is asking. Indeed, it is well-known that a morphism is continuous (in the course I've attended we have *defined* morphisms as "continuous maps that preserves regular functions"); moreover, the continuous image of an irreducible set is irreducible.

So I would just answer to the exercise by saying: $\phi(\phi^{-1}(Z))=Z$ and this is true for every *continuous* map. Why does the exercise give me a surjective morphism? Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The equality $\phi(\phi^{-1}(Z))=Z$ is generally only a containment $\phi(\phi^{-1}(Z))\subseteq Z$ for arbitrary $\phi$, but for $\phi$ surjective, it is equality.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Thanks for your comment. Of course you are right, so the claim is true for every continuous surjective map, am I right? I do not understand where one should use the hypothesis that $\phi$ is a morphism.

Comment: Dear @Romeo, Yes, it seems to me that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjective map of topological spaces and the inverse image of some set is irreducible, the set is irreducible.

Comment: btw, are you sure that it is only a containment? I thought it was $\phi^{-1}\phi(Z) \subset Z$ for arbitrary $\phi$ but $\phi\phi^{-1}(Z)=Z$ for every $\phi$.

Comment: Dear @Romeo, I don't understand what you're saying. For any map of sets $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$, and $Z\subseteq Y$, $\phi^{-1}(\phi(Z))\subseteq Z$, and this inclusion is an equality if $\phi$ is surjective, or more generally if $Z$ is contained in the image. In general $\phi(\phi^{-1}(Z))=\phi(X)\cap Z$.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment, it is senseless. You are perfectly right. So the exercise is "stupid" somehow; the claim holds true for every continous surjective map, we do not need morphism. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that $\phi(\phi^{-1}(Z)) = Z$ does not hold for any map and any $Z$, you need $Z \subseteq \phi(X)$.

Comment: But it does hold for surjective maps.